# Implementing Certificate Authentication on the Broswer

Tags: browser, ssl-certificate, smartcard

I'm looking for the proper documentation on how to do certificate authentication on the browser. There are often sites that trigger a popup window that prompts the users to select a certificate.  I'm looking into this particularly tp learn how to securely implemented smartcard auth support. Does anyone know where I can read more about this?

Comment: Please check if this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55757349/9659885) is useful.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have learned certificate authentication is handled between the client and the server. So the popup prompting the selection of a certificate is handled by the browser when the server responds saying that this is required for authentication. The server config would need to be updated to require smartcard authentication for requests.